# Using Xampp Filezilla to upload files

Tags: xampp, filezilla

I have installed xampp on windows 8 and would like to use the Filezilla that comes with it to upload files to remote servers.

However I am not really sure whether I am doing the right thing here...after some research it seems that the Filezilla included in the xampp is the SERVER-side Filezilla, not the CLIENT-side Filezilla.

Not really sure to understand the core difference between these two, but to make it simple do I need the CLIENT-side Filezilla to upload file to remote servers ?

THanks for your help,

Julien

Answer (score 0):

I only ever used client side to upload files to a server.

Below is a breif description I got [here](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration)

**Setting up FileZilla Client**
Passive mode

In passive mode, the client has no control over what port the server chooses for the data connection. Therefore, in order to use passive mode, you'll have to allow outgoing connections to all ports in your firewall.
Active mode

In active mode, the client opens a socket and waits for the server to establish the transfer connection.

**Setting up and testing FileZilla Server**

Setting up the server is very similar to setting up the client, with the main difference being that the roles of active and passive mode are reversed.